# Attendance clock in and out over midnight diffrence

Tags: php, time, clock, shift

I have an employee attendance system working fine within the same day but if the time passes midnight the total attendance is wrong, for example if my shift starts at 11:00 PM and finishes at 8:00 AM the next day.
Below is part of the code calculating the total hours:

```
// calculating total work
$total_work = $employee_last_clock_in->diff(new DateTime($data['clock_out']))->format('%H:%I');
$data['total_work'] = $total_work;
$data['clock_in_out'] = 0;
```

I do have another program simple like (Workday) that calculates correctly and it carrying out the total hours even in 2 different days, here is part of the code.

```
if($sched_in_time == NULL)
{
    $status_in = null;

} else {

    $sched_clock_in_time_24h = date("H.i", strtotime($sched_in_time));

    $time_in_24h = date("H.i", strtotime($clockin));

    if ($time_in_24h <= $sched_clock_in_time_24h) 
    {
        $status_in = trans("In Time");
    } else {
        $status_in = trans("Late In");
    }
}
```

How I can fix this issue or how I can update my first code to calculate the time even in different days ( after midnight )?

Comment: I run some tests with your code and it worked fine for me.  The only hypothesis I can see is the value of `$data['clock_out']` being incorrect.

Comment: FYI I used: `$employee_last_clock_in = new DateTime('2022-01-01 23:00:00');
$data['clock_out'] = '2022-01-02 07:05:00';` and it returned correctly the string "0805"

Comment: many thanks @RodrigoKravetz i appreciate your comments.
do you mean the value of $data['clock_out'] this :

$data['clock_out'] = $current_time->format('H:i');
                    $timeDifference = $shift_out->diff(new DateTime($data['clock_out']))->format('%H:%I');
     $data['early_leaving'] = $timeDifference;


i apologize for this misunderstanding 
please bare with me

Comment: Ok, let me see if I understand. if your code is really doing: `$data['clock_out'] = $current_time->format('H:i')`, then it is the source of the problem.  What is the result of `var_dump($data['clock_out'])`?

Comment: please allow my limited knowledge, i cant find anywhere to get the var_dump($data['clock_out'])
am just having the code open in VS Code and when i save i see the results in the browser.

what should be the correct one for $data['clock_out'] = $current_time->format('H:i')

sorry again

Comment: @RodrigoKravetz , thanks again for the help.

Comment: @RodrigoKravetz please if you are free can you guide me with the correct code for 
$data['clock_out'] = $current_time->format('H:i')

thank you

Comment: please is there anyone can help me on this as per RodrigoKravetz (comments) the main issue with this line.

$data['clock_out'] = $current_time->format('H:i')

how to rewrite it with correct arguments.

many thanks